# I got this error 'DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical'

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm going to train this as an xgboost model.

[image]

'start_time','end_time' column was in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

I changed it to string using astype(str) and changed it to yyyymmddhhmmss format using regular expressions.

```
xgb_model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(eta=0.1, nrounds=1000, max_depth=8, colsample_bytree=0.5, scale_pos_weight=1.1, booster='gbtree', 
                                  metric='multi:softmax')
hr_pred = xgb_model.fit(x_train, np.ravel(y_train, order='C')).predict(x_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, hr_pred))
```

But this kind of error occurred and I've never seen like this before.

> ```
> ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical.  When
>             categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter
>             `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.start_time, end_time
> ```

how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that you have categorial data. `Start_time` and `end_time` are object type.

You need either to drop them or to encode them.

To drop them

```
xgb_model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(eta=0.1, nrounds=1000, max_depth=8, colsample_bytree=0.5, scale_pos_weight=1.1, booster='gbtree', 
                                  metric='multi:softmax')
hr_pred = xgb_model.fit(x_train._get_numeric_data(), np.ravel(y_train, order='C')).predict(x_test._get_numeric_data())
print(classification_report(y_test, hr_pred))
```

To encode them have a look at this library https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/

Comment: @mineral If the answer has been helpful, it is nice to say thank you, but a the same time you should accept the answer to reward the person who has answered.

Comment: Note: I also had to do this even though my column types were `category`.

Comment: @kevin_theinfinityfund you need to feed numerical data in general to ML model, so the answer is similar. Either you drop or encode them

Comment: @CarlosMougan yes, I was just writing for someone else's knowledge. Their dataframe types were only `object` so I was informing that the same goes for `category`.